# How to change the location of a control from a groupbox to form in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

Not able to take out a control from a groupbox at runtime in vb.net.

see the code:

```
 For i as integer = 0 To groupbox1.Controls.Count - 1
        Dim ctrl As Control = groupbox1.Controls(i)
        If ctrl.text = "Test" then
           ctrl.Location = label1.Location
        End if
 Next
```

The control "Test" is a Textbox which is placed inside the groupBox1.
The control "label1" is a Label which is placed outside of the groupBox1. when we change the location of textbox, Its moved somewhere, not at label1.location.
is there any other way to do this?

Comment: The Control class doesn't have a "Caption" property.  How you managed to compile and run this code, let alone move anything, is very unclear.  You'll need to map a Location property relative to its container, changing the ctrl.Parent property to label1.Parent is best.

Comment: Always use `Option Strict On`. Currently you must have `Option Strict Off` in order to compile this code (assuming the code in your post really is exactly the code you are using). +1 to Hans for suggesting `Parent` rather than `Location`

Comment: @HansPassant He assign  a txtBox with `groupbox1.Controls(i)`. Poor naming though.

Comment: I have edited my post. plz check it.

Comment: Just changing Location is not enough.  You will have to remove the control from the GroupBox Controls collection and add it to the Form's controls collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ctrl.Parent = Form1
```

And then change the location:

```
ctrl.Location = Label1.Location
```

Comment: What if the current form isn't Form1?  I'd use "Me" instead...

Comment: Its just an example... `Form1` makes clearer the answer, IMHO